# Why can't I open Chrome tab in Chrome with URL: "chrome://inspect" from Chrome launcher

Tags: node.js, google-chrome

I am trying to use [chrome launcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-launcher) (in node.js) to open a chrome tab in the url chrome://inspect/, but it opens n empty Chrome empty tab, and by that I mean the main page of Chrome. However, when I enter a "regular" url, for example "www.google.com", it opens the right page.

Does anyone know maybe what I'm doing wrong, and if its possible to open chrome in the chrome://inspect/ page?

Here you can see what actually gets opened:

[image]

Thanks.